# Creating an If statement within a lumbda function

Tags: python

Is it possible to write an "if statement" into a lambda functions in python? I am trying to write something along these lines but I am getting a syntax error after the if statement:

```
filt_sin = snf.generic_filter(lambda x: np.std(sin, (size, size) if x<=sin_std), sin, size=size, mode="nearest")
```

Comment: It is possible, but not in the way you did it. What do you want your `if` to do exactly ? What should it do if `x>sin_std` ?

Comment: If x>sin_std for a given (size, size) array I don't want that filter to operate in that section. I want the filter to "move on" to the next (size, size) array.

Comment: So what do you want your lambda function to return in that case ? That's my question. `sin_std` is a variable defined outside all of that ? And what's `snf.generic_filter`?

Comment: I have edited the statement to read:

filt_sin = snf.generic_filter(sin, lambda x: (np.sum(sin(x) * window) / np.sum(window)) if np.std(x) <= sin_std else sin(x), size=ws, mode="nearest")

But now I am getting an exit code -107374157. I believe this is a stack overflow error, any advice on how to over come this?

Answer (score 2):

The thing to understand is that whatever *single expression* is to the right of the `:` is what your `lambda` function will return.  If you want your lambda to return `None` under certain conditions, you can use a ternary expression, e.g.:

```
lambda x: foo(x) if x > y else None
```

Keywords like `if: ... else: ...` and `for ... in ...:` that introduce indented blocks do not work within the scope of a `lambda` definition, but you *can* use ternary expressions, generator expressions, etc.

Comment: I have edited the statement to read: filt_sin = snf.generic_filter(sin, lambda x: (np.sum(sin(x) * window) / np.sum(window)) if np.std(x) <= sin_std else sin(x), size=ws, mode="nearest") But now I am getting an exit code -107374157. I believe this is a stack overflow error, any advice on how to over come this?